# how to show hide div on focus input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

How to show hide div upon  existing div, existing div should be hide.

## My existing div

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<input class="abc" type="text" />
</div>
</div>
```

## My Hide Div which are i want show on click action

```
<div class="container newone">
<div class="row">
<span>some text here</span>
</div>
</div>
```

## css

```
.newone{ position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0px; display:none;}
```

Comment: perhaps a full jsfiddle would make it clearer what you are asking for.

Comment: You tagged `JS`, but there is no `JS` code, show what have you tired so far.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask. Hint: Show effort and code in a [mcve]

Comment: @MehdiDehghani i dont write js for this things, i want solve in JS . thanks

Comment: @UDigi I see, but I think you suppose to try something and then try to get help. I think if you try something (even if could get success) you can learn more about that vs someone do that for you.

Answer (score 3):

this should work

```
 $(function() {

    $(".abc").focusin(function() {
        $(".newone").show();
    }).focusout(function () {
        $(".newone").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `focus` and `focusout` events of an input to hide and show a related message using javascript:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('myinput');
var message = document.getElementsByClassName('newone')[0];
input.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    message.style.display = 'block';
});
input.addEventListener('focusout', function() {
    message.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
.newone { 
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <input class="abc" type="text" id='myinput'/>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <span>some text here </span>
    <span>some text here</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container newone">
  <div class="row">
    <span>some text here</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `addClass` to hide the div using jQuery, Please refer the below code.

```
$( ".container" ).addClass( "newone" );
```

For more info please refer the below url

https://api.jquery.com/addclass/